# How can I load a "platform-independent" image using SkiaSharp?

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

Just like I can specify a simple name, like `photo.png` in `Image.Source` and it pulls the right image (at the correct resolution) for each platform, how can I do the same to load an `SKBitmap`? In the examples I've seen, people use the full path to the file or resource, but my images are contained in each platform project at various resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is create a separate implementation for each platform to load each image as the native class. Bitmap on Android and I think UIImage on IOS. Doing everything nativly allows you to pull from the folders each platform can use. The trick to get this to be an skbitmap is to save each one into a memory stream. The memory stream has a method that can convert the image to a byte array which you can use in the constructor in a skbitmap.